# Unity menu raise on click

Tags: unity, focus

I am using Unity on Ubuntu 16.04

A user window is split into a menu bar and the internal window.

When I click on the interior I do not want the window raised.
When I click on the menu bar, I do want the window raised.

Is there any way to achieve this?